# Changed partition of disk, without updating lvm, now can't remove PV from LVM

Tags: linux, lvm

In an effort to adjust my `/home/{user}` directory size, I decided to carve up some space on a drive that I wasn't aware was within the LVM groups already. I was able to successfully delete the partition (1.8T in all) and carved it into a bunch of 500G partitions, so I could mix and match space as needed.

I delete `/dev/sdb3` (1.8T) and made `/dev/sdb3` (~500G), `/dev/sdb4` (~500G) `/dev/sdb5` (~500G), `/dev/sdb6` (~300G) on the partition table.

I was able to successfully add `/dev/sdb4` through `/dev/sdb6` as physical volumes, then I realized my mistake. `/dev/sdb3` was an LVM physical and is still listed as 1.8T.

I have tried to remove the data on it to the other drives (there is nothing on it I want to save BTW). That failed because there isn't enough space.

I also tried to remove it, and force that remove. No dice. It is `in use`

So now I am stuck. I am not sure how I go about solving this issue. I have a PV that is shown as 1.8T that is not actually, and I'd like to remove it or get it to reflect the proper size of the partition.

Answer (score 0):

After mucking around with all things `pv*` and `vg*` I came down to just removing the volume group that the physical volume was a part of. A bit heavy handed, but it worked in this case, so here is what I ran:

`sudo vgremove fedora`

where `fedora` was the name of the volume group that I removed. This release the PV from use, and it dropped out immediately allowing the new `/dev/sdb3` PV to drop into place.

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line option that you may pass to `vgreduce`:

```
vgreduce --removemissing system
```